# How to calculate the real length of lines in the image?

Tags: image-processing

I want to calculate the size of square flooring tiles in the image. But nearer lines in the image are longer than further lines. Are there any methods to calculate the real length of red lines?
I have known the angle between smartphone and ground.

Flooring tiles image :

[image: flooring tiles image]

Comment: This is not a trivial project. My iPhone has a built-in app that does just this. It builds up a 3D model of a surface over time, while I move the phone around the surface. With that model, I am able to place points on the surface, and the app is able to tell me the distance between those points. But you need to build that 3D model of the real world, and that is not trivial. Search [SLAM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your comment. I think SLAM seems too difficult for me. Is it going to be easier if I assume camera height from ground is 1m6? I don't need result exactly in mm, cm is fine.